# Reading a complete text file using for loop

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I am trying to read a text file using a for loop that runs for a 100 times.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("client.txt");    
for (int i=0;i<=100;i++)
{ 
   reader.readline();
}
```

Now this works fine if the text file has 100 lines but not if lets say 700. So I want the loop to run for 100 times but read "1%" of the file in each run.How would i do that?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant read the entire file into memory then manipulate it from there?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94223t4d.aspx but File.ReadAllLines is much nicer.

Comment: well a progress bar is showing the "File Read" progress. So i need it to run for 100 times in the for loop.Thats why i am not reading the whole file...

Comment: @ChrisMetzen This looks wrong to me... to sacrifice perf for showing progress..... If your file is big enough  it will automatically show the progress since it will take time to read the file.

Comment: @ChrisMetzen please see an updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If file size is not too large you can:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("client.txt");
```

or

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("client.txt");
```

Reading 1% at a time is a bit tricky, I'd go with the approach of reading line by line:

```
var filename = "client.txt";
var info = new FileInfo(filename);
var text = new StringBuilder();

using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        text.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine());
        var progress = Convert.ToDouble(stream.Position) * 100 / info.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(progress);
    }
}

var result = text.ToString();
```

But please notice, the progress will not be very accurate because `StreamReader.ReadLine` (and equivalently `ReadLineAsync`) will often read more than just a single line - it basically reads into a buffer and then interprets that buffer. That's much more efficient than reading a single byte at a time, but it does mean that the stream will have advanced further than it strictly speaking needs to.